# Python: How can I input variables instead of inputting strings in .append() function?

Tags: python

So this is my code:

```py
if spot == 4:
        exec("ch" + str(spot) + " = " + "vl" + str(spot) )
        displayword.append(ch4)
    else:
        exec("ch" + str(spot) + " = " + "'_'")
        displayword.append( ("ch"+str(spot) ))
```

My output on the word orange would be:

> Orange
> ['ch0', 'ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3', ' g ', 'ch5']

So when I use `displayword.append(ch4)`, I get the value of ch4 but when I just `"ch" + str(spot)` I simply get that value as a string value.. I tried `exec (("ch"+str(spot) )  )`, but I just got `None` as the values in the list..

Comment: a better approach would be to use dictionaries, e.g. `d = {"spot": "value_of_spot"}`

Comment: Anytime you find yourself using `exec`, your first thought should be either "What did I do wrong?" or "How can I avoid using `exec`?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use lots of similarly named variables; use a `dict` for both `ch` and `vl`.

```
if spot == 4:
    ch["4"] = vl["4"]
else:
    ch[spot] = '_'

# Or
# ch[spot] = vl["4"] if spot == 4 else '_'

displayword.append(ch[spot])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, however how can I assign letters to the vl variable based of dictionaries? because I used:         exec("vl" + str(spot) + " = " + " ' " + x_vc + " ' ") to assign 1 variable to each letter

Comment: `vl[spot] = x_vc`?

Comment: Yep got it, my issue was I was defining my dicts and lists and thats why the vl[spot] = x_vc line wasnt workin, thanks for all your help chep!